# Toshiba eStudio-242 installation error

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printer, port

I'm having this quite peculiar problem while trying to install this printer through USB.

Recently, I formatted my system and reinstalled Windows 7 Pro (x64) and I can not reinstall this printer anymore. It was fine before the format of the pc.

I tried installing driver from CD that came along with the printer but all in vain.

I also downloaded driver from [this official website](https://www.toshiba-business.com.au/support/drivers/details?Term=e-STUDIO242) and install it's the same. These are the screenshot below after I run application & install the printer driver.
[image]
[image]

And if I try to forcefully install driver from device manager then it's the only result that I get.

[image]
[image]

Apparantly, the printer is not getting installed in the correct port no matter how much I try.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

1. Uninstall the installed printer driver.
2. Restart the computer.
3. Download the following printer driver according to the official website you provided and decompress print driver:

[image]

4. Right-click e-Studio242 in this screenshot.[image]
5. Select update driver, select the printer driver we just downloaded and saved in the directory.
6. When we installed, we check if the e-Studio242 is in printer support->Universal Serial Bus Controllers, if so, it should be OK.